# Homestead not showing my site after box upgrade

Tags: laravel, vagrant, homestead

I updated my laravel/homestead box to version 8 and now my site is not on the vagrant machine. I've searched and read numerous posts already and all say to provision yet I've done that. My ~/code/ directory is empty on the vagrant box.

When I bring the machine up, it does say this:

```
==> homestead-7: Running provisioner: shell...
    homestead-7: Running: script: Creating Site: listingnaples.test
```

However, there's no listingnaples.test within `~/code/`. It is on my local machine though.

**EDIT**: I should note that I have run `vagrant provision` and it doesn't fix this problem.

Contents of my Homestead.yaml:

```
---
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 1
provider: virtualbox

authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - ~/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
    - map: ~/code
      to: /home/vagrant/code

sites:
    - map: listingnaples.test
      to: /home/vagrant/code/listingnaples/public
    - map: blog.listingnaples.test
      to: /home/vagrant/code/blog.listingnaples.com

databases:
    - homestead
    - RETS
```

Please help! I'm dead in the water without it!

Comment: Please note that homestead 8 is currently in alpha mode and you're explicitly told not to update if you don't know what you're doing: https://github.com/laravel/homestead/releases/tag/v8.0.0-alpha2 . Easiest is probably to remove the v8 version of the box and revert to v7.2.1 or something.

Comment: try `vagrant destroy` and then `vagrant up`.